# When is the algebraic connectivity a simple eigenvalue of the graph Laplacian？

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, graph-laplacian

For a simple graph, we know that the second smallest eigenvalue of its Laplacian matrix is called the algebraic connectivity.

My question is when the algebraic connectivity is a simple eigenvalue, or what type of graph structure can guarantee this fact?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Guo, Feng and Zhang give some examples of trees with simple connectivity in [On the multiplicity of laplacian eigenvalues of graphs](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10587-010-0063-x). More generally, multiplicity of algebraic connectivity is discussed in [The perturbed Laplacian matrix of a graph by Bapat, Pati and Kirkland](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233362769_The_perturbed_Laplacian_matrix_of_a_graph). But if you are hoping for a simple condition that guarantees simplicity there isn't any. For example, their Corollary 8 states that the algebraic connectivity is simple if there is a cut vertex with exactly two Perron components.

Let $v$ be a cut vertex of a connected graph $G$, removing which splits it into connected components $G_i$. Such a component is called Perron component if the least eigenvalue of the principal submatrix of the Laplacian matrix of $G$ corresponding to $G_i$ is minimal among the least eigenvalues of these components. They prove that this happens if and only if the least eigenvalue does not exceed the algebraic connectivity of $G$ itself.